# receive mail read receipt nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I was hoping you could help me with the following problem:

I wrote with NodeJs a simple mail client to send a mail to a list of recipients. To do that, I used an npm library called nodemailer that made the job easier.
I was looking for a way to get a notification or a any kind of receipt that notifies me when one of the recipients opens the mail I sent them.

I can't find any library or method to implement this.
Is there any library I could use to get a read receipt?

Comment: consider this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082188/email-opened-not-tracking-from-nodejs-nodemailer

Answer (score 1):

consider this image here

```
 <html>
  <body>
  <img 
 src="https://YOUR_SITE.com/track/this/image/UNIQUE_ID_FOR_THIS_IMAGE.jpg">
  </body>
 </html>
```

here is link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082188/email-opened-not-tracking-from-nodejs-nodemailer)

Comment: This is gold, so simple and effective